# Check if CDC is enabled on database and table in SQL Server by query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cdc

How check if CDC is enabled on specific database and table in SQL Server by running a SQL query?

Comment: `sys.databases.is_cdc_enabled`, `sys.tables.is_tracked_by_cdc`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation for [sys.sp_cdc_enable_db (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sys-sp-cdc-enable-db-transact-sql?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16) in the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sys-sp-cdc-enable-db-transact-sql?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16#remarks) section:

> `sys.sp_cdc_enable_db` creates the change data capture objects that have database wide scope, including meta data tables and DDL triggers. It also creates the cdc schema and cdc database user and sets the `is_cdc_enabled` column for the database entry in the [`sys.databases`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) catalog view to `1`.

```sql
select
  name,
  is_cdc_enabled
from sys.databases;
```

From the documentation for [sys.sp_cdc_enable_table (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sys-sp-cdc-enable-table-transact-sql?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16), also in the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sys-sp-cdc-enable-table-transact-sql?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16#remarks) section:

> `sys.sp_cdc_enable_table` also creates the capture and cleanup jobs for the database if the source table is the first table in the database to be enabled for change data capture and no transactional publications exist for the database. It sets the `is_tracked_by_cdc` column in the [`sys.tables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) catalog view to `1`.

```sql
select
  name,
  is_tracked_by_cdc 
from sys.tables;
```